# Listing SQL Server instance startup parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, configuration, t-sql

I have a server I have just restarted and verified which trace flag are active using `DBCC TRACESTATUS`:

[image]

> Trace Flag : 3688 Function: Removes messages to errorlog about traces
>   started and stopped

Here you can see [what each trace flag does.](http://www.sqlservice.se/updated-microsoft-sql-server-trace-flag-list/)

[Flag 3688](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922578)

The start parameters are as follows:

[image]

Question:

How can I find what the startup parameters of the SQL Server services are, through T-SQL?

Comment: And (for my own forgetful memory) that dialogue box is in “Sql Server Configuration Manager”: SQL Server configuration Manager > SQL Server Services. R-click SQL Server (INSTANCE) > Properties > Startup parameters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 or later, this is made considerably easier via the [sys.dm_server_registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204561.aspx) DMV:

```
SELECT
    DSR.registry_key,
    DSR.value_name,
    DSR.value_data
FROM sys.dm_server_registry AS DSR
WHERE 
    DSR.registry_key LIKE N'%MSSQLServer\Parameters';
```

From: [An easier way to get SQL Server startup parameters](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbadmin/an-easier-way-to-get/)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using 2008 R2 and above(I can see you tagged question as SQL Server 2014)  you can use DMV [sys.dm_server_registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh204561.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get all information about registry values for SQL Server.

Just go to SSMS and run below

```
select * from sys.dm_server_registry
```

If you want to filter out parameters related to SQL Server startup

```
SELECT r.registry_key, r.value_name, r.value_data
FROM sys.dm_server_registry r
WHERE r.registry_key LIKE N'%MSSQLServer\Parameters'
```

You can find [similar blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbadmin/an-easier-way-to-get/) related to what you were asking.

You can also use undocumented xp_reagread command